# Delete any repeated values in a set of lines

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a file consist of many of lines where each line consist of two valuess like:

```
    53539 14390
    14390 49489
    52882 49489
    23623 14390
    23623 7554
    23678 14390
        .
        .
        .
```

I wrote a c code to read those lines and store them in two tables T1 & T2 where:

```
T1[0][1]= 53539 & T2[0][1]= 14390
T1[1][1]= 14390 & T2[1][1]= 49489
T1[2][1]= 52882 & T2[2][1]= 49489
   .
   .
   .
```

And everything was OK...I know that I can store both value's in one table but I thought for my program it is better to define two different tables especially for the following purpose

The second thing I tried to do is to search all value's and to specify and count ONLY the number of unrepeated value's in both tables (I mean unique value's in both columns which are the values occurs only once in both tables ) like in my example: The unrepeated values are: 53539, 52882, 7554 & 23678 so the number is 4

**The Problem is** the second part of my code is not working in a good way, it gives me wrong values and I tried to solve it but it is still not working!!

I know that my question is so easy for all programmers but in fact I am a beginner in c and coding.

You can see down below my code attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define nOfLines 6


int main()
    {


FILE *file;
int i, j, ii, jj;
int T1[nOfLines][1], T2[nOfLines][1];
file=fopen("ngc.txt","r");



for(i=0; i < nOfLines ; i++) {
    fscanf(file,"%d %d", &T1[i][1], &T2[i][1]);
    printf("%d %d\n ",  T1[i][1], T2[i][1]);
   }



  int z=0;
  for(i=0; i < nOfLines ; i++) {
  for(j=0; j < nOfLines ; j++) {

  if ((T1[i][1] == T1[j][1]) || (T1[i][1] == T2[i][1]) || (T2[i][1] == T2[j][1]))
   {
  break;
  }

  printf("%d %d\n", T1[i][0], z);
  z++;
  printf("%d %d\n", T2[i][1], z);
  z++;
  }
  }
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
  }
```

P.S: I wrote a loop because I have a huge number of lines so it is impossible to enter insert each value in this code **ALSO** I tried to do something like:

```
 if (!found(T1[i][1])) {printf("%d %d\n", T1[i][1], z);z++;}
 if (!found(T2[i][1])) {printf("%d %d\n", T2[i][1], z);z++;}
```

But it did not work!!

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks in advance...

Comment: `int T1[nOfLines][1]` only has *one element* in its second dimension, which can only be indexed by `0` and not by `1` as you are doing. Ditto for `T2`.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for information but it can read data correctly!!

Comment: You were unlucky that it didn't fail, so you still think it is right.

Comment: So it should be T1[nOfLines][0] & T2[nOfLines][0] instead of ...

Comment: If you're working with only two values and you have two separate arrays, there's no reason to make them two-dimensional arrays. You could just as easily make them each a 1-dimensional and achieve the same results. Alternatively, you could set it so that every value is entered into one two-dimensional array where each value of a row would be `T1[rowNumber][colNumber]` Additionally, you're setting and getting values that are out of your initialized range. You really should look up how arrays are indexed in c or you will without a doubt run into problems.

Comment: @D.R. thank for advice...As I said, since I am beginner in programing  I thought it is easier to compare values and find the unrepeated ones if they are in different arrays

Comment: [`std::set` is a container that only contains unique values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). Add all of the values to the set as you read them in and then call the `size` method to get a count of values in the `set`. This may not be the fastest way to count unique values, but it is probably the easiest.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks but isn't  "std::set" only for C++

Comment: Well smurf. This question came up when I pulled a list of unanswered C++ questions. Didn't even look at the tags. Sorry about that.

Comment: The posted code doesn't even compile, much less deliver answers (right or wrong). A large chunk of what appears to be functional code is outside of any function. And `for(j=O;` is certainly not going to compile. That's a `'O'` (the letter), not a zero `0`. *Post real code*. Finally, turn up your compiler warnings. There are plenty that will tell you most of what comments here are saying.

Comment: "I thought it is easier to compare values and find the unrepeated ones if they are in different arrays" Maybe, maybe not. But the closer one value is to another in memory, the faster a modern CPU can typically access it because it has likely already been loaded into one high-speed cache or another.

Comment: @WhozCraig I said that I am new to programing so I don't know what do you mean by compiler warnings, in the other side I am trying to learn more... BTW, I use the terminal on my Linux to compile codes.

Comment: For either clang or gcc (you're very likely using one of those) add these switches to your compile line: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`. It should look like this: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic yourfile.c`. All warnings tripped will be considered errors, and especially for beginners, that is how they should be treated. It is a near-certainty that the logic flow is broken, or a language abuse is happening.

Comment: Quick rule of thumb: A Compiler Error means the code is syntactically incorrect (bad grammar, basically) and cannot be interpreted as an executable program. A Compiler Warning means the syntax is correct and the code can be executed, but the code does something questionable that will likely produce undesirable results. In other words, you can run a program that compiled with warnings, but it probably won't do what you want. Warnings are your first line of defense against runtime errors. After that it's static and dynamic analyser programs, debugging software, and the Mark 1 eyeball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store every values in a tab, as you did. Then you can iterate throught that tab and compare each value with the others. Let's say your tab is set with the values, here is an example of what you might do :

```
void deleteRepeatedValues(int* tab)
{
    int size = strlen(tab);
    for (int i = 0; i != size; i++) // For each value of the tab
    {
        if (tab[i] != 0) // If the value hasn't already be set to 0
        {
           for (int j = i; j != size; j++)
           {
                if (tab[i] == tab[j]) // We verify that the value after aren't the same
                    tab[j] = 0; // If they are, we set them to 0
           }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then write a function to make a new array out of this one without the zero-valued parts of the array. Something like that :

```
deleteRepeatedValues(tab);
int size = sizeof(tab);
int correctedTab[size];
int i = 0;
int y = 0;
while(i != size)
{
    if (tab[i] != 0) // If the value is not repeated
    {
        correctedTab[y] = tab[i]; // We copy it
        y++; // And advance in the corrected tab
    } // Otherwise we don't
    i++; // And only go further in `tab`
}
```

I can't test this code so far, and I haven't tried to adapt it to what you already done. This is a hint on a way to do what you wanted to do.

Also, I advise you to test wether opening and closing your files has succeeded or not. It might avoid a lot of problems.

Comment: `sizeof(tab);` is utterly wrong in the first function. That's the size, in bytes, of a *pointer*.

Comment: but your code is comparing the values in one array and there are 2 in my case !!